# How to create nested objects using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've upgraded to Rails 2.3.3 (from 2.1.x) and I'm trying to figure out the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method.  I can use the method to update existing nested objects, but I can't use it to create new nested objects.  Given the contrived example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  validates_presence_of :product_id, :body
end
```

If I try to create a new `Product`, with a nested `Note`, as follows:

```
params = {:name => 'Test', :notes_attributes => {'0' => {'body' => 'Body'}}}
p = Product.new(params)
p.save!
```

It fails validations with the message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Notes product can't be blank
```

I understand why this is happening -- it's because of the `validates_presence_of :product_id` on the `Note` class, and because at the time of saving the new record, the `Product` object doesn't have an `id`.  However, I don't want to remove this validation; I think it would be incorrect to remove it.

I could also solve the problem by manually creating the `Product` first, and then adding the `Note`, but that defeats the simplicity of `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Is there a standard Rails way of creating nested objects on new records?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a common, circular dependency issue. There is an [existing LightHouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/1943) which is worth checking out.

I expect this to be much improved in Rails 3, but in the meantime you'll have to do a workaround. One solution is to set up a virtual attribute which you set when nesting to make the validation conditional.

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  validates_presence_of :product_id, :unless => :nested
  attr_accessor :nested
end
```

And then you would set this attribute as a hidden field in your form.

```
<%= note_form.hidden_field :nested %>
```

That should be enough to have the `nested` attribute set when creating a note through the nested form. *Untested.*

Comment: In Rails 3 this problem is solved by the added :inverse_of option to has_many, has_one and belongs_to. See e.g. http://www.daokaous.com/rails3.0.0_doc/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001988 under the section "Bi-directional associations"

Comment: I've opted to disable the validation when :id == nil. Since that should only happen when writing a new, nested record, I'm hoping that will be safe. Odd that this issue made it all the way to 2.3.8.

Comment: inverse_of doesn't seem to work when both the record's parent doesn't exist yet, and thus no id can be tested.  Looks like this nested hack is the only way through. :(

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue in Rails 3, any updates on how to solve it?

Answer (score 7):

check this document if you use Rails3.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#label-Validating+the+presence+of+a+parent+model

Comment: very important point is you should validate presence of "product" not "product_id"

Comment: I think kuboon has the right answer.  Validate presence of "product", not "product_id" along with changing the association on Product to "has_many :notes, inverse_of: :product" should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Ryan's solution is actually really cool.
I went and made my controller fatter so that this nesting wouldn't have to appear in the view. Mostly because my view is sometimes json, so I want to be able to get away with as little as possible in there.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :note
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  validates_presence_of :product_id  unless :nested
  attr_accessor :nested
end

class ProductController < ApplicationController

def create
    if params[:product][:note_attributes]
       params[:product][:note_attributes].each { |attribute| 
          attribute.merge!({:nested => true})
    }
    end
    # all the regular create stuff here  
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution yet is to use parental_control plugin: http://github.com/h-lame/parental_control