# Is it really needed to validate foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 and, after post my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344059/trouble-with-foreign-key-validations-when-using-accepts-nested-attributes-for), I would like to know and understand if (or not) to *explicitly* validate foreign keys related to `ActiveRecord::Associations` is needed. For example:

```
class CategoryAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, :foreign_key => 'article_id'
  belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => 'category_id'

  validates :article_id, :presence => true, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
  validates :category_id, :presence => true, :numericality => { :only_integer => true }
end
```

Are above `validates` methods *really* needed? Why?

Comment: An association only makes sense when it describes an existing article and category. You need these constraints to keep your database consistent. What's the point of associating an article with "nothing"?

Comment: @Tom - Should I state validation methods *explicitly* (as I made in the question)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not do it the way you're doing it, but I would do:

```
validates_presence_of :article, :category
```

I'm not sure its absolutely necessary, but this prevents you from being able to save only a partial association. It would be hard to create a partial association in normal rails usage, but this way it would not happen.

Also, you don't need `foreign_key` on either of those associations, just

```
belongs_to :article, :category
```

Comment: Doesn't that add some serious overhead to the app? Wouldn't it be better to add constraints at the db level?

Comment: That depends on your app and how you define serious overhead. If this is user-facing and users are CRUD'ing a few records at a time, this is not going to add a measurable impact. If you're doing something as an admin with a million records at a time, it may be meaningful overhead. But, if you're doing something as an admin with a million records at a time, you probably shouldn't be doing it in the application code in the first place.